# Spring MVC service factory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics

I have generic service in my application that has autowired generic repository (R extends CrudRepository) as a property. Also it uses entity type parameter (E extends IdEntity). So it looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class IdEntity
```

for entity,

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SimpleRepository<E extends IdEntity> extends CrudRepository<E, Long>
```

for repository and

```
public interface SimpleService<E>
```

for service. I want use this generics in the way like

```
SimpleService<User> service
```

But when I try to do this Spring can't understand what I want and give me IdEntity instead of User. To prevent this I need to create empty classes (like UserService extends SimpleService) or define them in xml or Application-class with annotation @Bean. 
 Is there a way to create some kind of factory that will return object I want? Like this:

```
return new SimpleServiceImpl<E, SimpleRepository<E>>() { }
```